# clustering features based on the boundaries in openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, geoserver

Is it possible to make clustering based on polygons? We want to cluster the features based on the boundaries of each city or province.

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly I think your will need create separate cluster layers for each province, then the features will only cluster with other features in that layer/province.

Comment: @Milke yes,You got it right